# SPEL expression in @EventListener

Tags: spring-kafka

The below code sample is taken from Spring documentation. My question is how to pass a variable in place of 'qux-'. I tried #{}, ${}.

```
@EventListener(condition = "event.listenerId.startsWith('qux-')")
    public void eventHandler(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done, but indirectly...

```
@Bean
String prefix(@Value("${foo:qux-}") String foo) {
    return foo;
}
```

and

```
@EventListener(condition = "event.listenerId.startsWith(@prefix)")
```

It will use `qux-` if there is no property `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

When using EL with Spring Boot, you need to surround the whole expression with #{} and inside, you must use ${} so you can retrieve the variable from your application context.
So in your case, this should work:

`@EventListener(condition = "#{'event.listenerId'.startsWith(${'myVariable'})}")`

Comment: Expressions like that, and resolving placeholders, are not currently supported by `@EventListener`. If they were, it would be `"event.listenerId.startsWith('${myVariable}'}`.